# Terraform ignore specific create resource. Terraform Drift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am attempting to remediate some Terraform drift. My Terraform code creates three AWS EC2 Instances in a loop using `for_each`, each with attached EBS volumes. In the console, someone removed and attached a new EBS Volume to one of the instances. Now, when I run `terraform apply`, Terraform wants to recreate the original EBS volume and attach it, as shown below:

```
  # module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_ebs_volume.this["backup_/dev/sdm"] will be created
  + resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
      + arn               = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2a"
      + encrypted         = true
      + final_snapshot    = false
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + iops              = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id        = "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-2:0000000:key/6d3d064e-0000-0000-9429-7a6fe133b7cb"
      + size              = 1024
      + snapshot_id       = (known after apply)
      + tags              = {
          + "BackupDaily"            = "true"
          + "BackupYearly"           = "false"
          + "Environment"            = "stg"
          + "Name"                   = "stg-db02-backup"
          + "OperationalEnvironment" = "stg"
          + "Patch Group"            = "stg-patch-rhel"
          + "Project"                = "Stg"
          + "ResourceGroup"          = "db"
        }
      + tags_all          = {
          + "BackupDaily"            = "true"
          + "BackupYearly"           = "false"
          + "Environment"            = "stg"
          + "Name"                   = "stg-db02-backup"
          + "OperationalEnvironment" = "stg"
          + "Patch Group"            = "stg-patch"
          + "Project"                = "Stg"
          + "ResourceGroup"          = "db"
        }
      + throughput        = (known after apply)
      + type              = "gp3"
    }

  # module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_volume_attachment.this["backup_/dev/sdm"] will be created
  + resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this" {
      + device_name = "/dev/sdm"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + instance_id = "i-0000000000000"
      + volume_id   = (known after apply)
    }
```

I don't want this to happen. Is there a way I can stop Terraform from recreating? The problem is that they are created in a loop, so I can't simply remove the attachment part, as it will remove the volume from the other two EC2 instances.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken what you need is `terraform import`... look at the documentation of those resources is trying to create for more details on how to do it

Comment: The new EBS volume attached on the Instance has a different name (backup_/dev/sdl), so if i use TF import, itll try change its name from sdl to sdm which wouldnt work

Comment: you should bring that sdl to sdm in the question ... not much you can do other than let it recreate via terraform then manually copy anything that is on the other volume

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the following actions:

- remove the previous resources from the state

  ```
  terraform state rm 'module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_ebs_volume.this["backup_/dev/sdm"]'
  terraform state rm 'module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_volume_attachment.this["backup_/dev/sdm"]'
  ```
- update the config resources with the new resource names `backup_/dev/sdl`
- import the new resources:

  ```
  terraform import 'module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_ebs_volume.this["backup_/dev/sdl"]' <VOLUME ID>
  terraform import 'module.stg.module.db_ec2[1].aws_volume_attachment.this["backup_/dev/sdl"]' <DEVICE_NAME:VOLUME_ID:INSTANCE_ID>
  ```
- execute a `terraform plan` to observe the config versus actual differences, and update the config to match the actuals
- explain to the person how the resources are managed so this does not occur again